# Meaning of "to shoot the spot"

Tags: sentence-meaning

In the episode 14 of *Friends*, Susan and Carol are having dinner in a restaurant. Susan's cell phone rings - it's a workmate who needs her presence there. Then, they talk to each other:

> Carol: Oh no. I thought you said they could **shoot the spot** without you.
>
> Susan: I thought they could.
>
> Carol: But it is Valentine’s Day.
>
> Susan: I know, but it is my job. Look, I’ll try to get back as soon as I can. I’m sorry.

I've been trying to understand the meaning of the bold expression above checking different meanings to *to shoot* and *spot*, but I couldn't. I guess Susan's job was not presented on the series (so far). To *spot* I found:

> *spot*. A situation, especially a troublesome one.

I think it may be the right meaning in this case, if *to shoot* could be like *to solve*. However, I couldn't be sure of that. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *shoot* is to film or take a picture of something. *the spot* is some short such activity like a commercial or promo.

Comment: What @user3169 said. Personally, I'd be perfectly happy with ***slot*** instead of ***shot*** in this context - more explicitly alluding to the idea that the transmission (or recording) schedule is "tight" (potentially making it difficult for additional material to be "slotted in" to some small gap).

Comment: @user3169 - You ought to convert that into an answer.

Comment: @J.R. I didn't because dictionary definitions applied to the context should have been enough to answer the question.

Comment: @user3169 - Have you looked up _spot_ in the dictionary? I think sometimes we forget how hard it might be for a learner to sort through [dozens of definitions](http://www.wordnik.com/words/spot) and spot the correct one. Given that _spot_ has about 20 definitions as a noun, and _shoot_ has about [40 as a verb](http://www.wordnik.com/words/shoot), that's about 800 possible potential meanings for _shoot the spot_.

Comment: I think the OP needs to apply the context to those definitions. Then [*spot*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spot): "6. countable noun - A spot in a television or radio show is a part of it that is regularly reserved for a particular performer or type of entertainment.
*Unsuccessful at screen writing, he got a spot on a CNN film show.*"

Comment: And [*shoot*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shoot): "7. - verb - When people shoot a film or shoot photographs, they make a film or take photographs using a camera. *He'd love to shoot his film in Cuba.  Three CBS cameramen were on site to shoot and edit taped reports.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user3169 pointed, in this situation, the right meanings to *shoot* and *spot* are:

> *shoot*. film or photograph (a scene, film, etc.).
>
> *spot*. a brief announcement or advertisement broadcast between scheduled radio or television programs.